# How can i use single category table for having category in Posts, Pages and Advertisement Section in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i need some help regarding using single category db table for all categories in my application. I want to have a single table which contains  all type of categories.

And when creating a Post , i would like to display only Post Model related Categories and while creating a Page i would like to display only Page Related Categories for selection.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vivek Bora it is very simple just add type column in your categories table 
Ex: type = post or advertisement or anything that you want.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the hint, I was thinking of implementing it in a complex way like using relationships and all, so this way didn't hit my mind. Will implement it this way :)

Comment: please mark it as an answer  so that it can help to others.